# 1D Wave PDE with "strange" Boundary Conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I've just arrived home from an exam and cannot come to terms with the fact I couldn't solve the following question:

Find a solution to

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
        u_{tt} - u_{xx}=0, & x>0, t>0 \\
        u(x,0)=u_t(x,0)=0, & x>0 \\
        u(0,t)=e^t \sin{t}, & t>0 \\ 
\end{array}.
\right.
$$

I tried separation of variables and failed miserably.
I have no idea how to approach the problem, but maybe it's because I'm tired after looking at it for 3,5h hours straight. At some point I even started questioning if the problem was well-posed.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: How can we have both $u(t,0)=e^t\sin t$ and $u(x,0)=0$?  Did you mean to write something different from this?

Comment: I just copied the question from the exam "ipsis verbis". I also thought it was weird, but then I assumed it was a typo and was meant to be read as $u(0,t)=e^t \sin{t}$.

Comment: OK.  That is different from the condition initially written.

Comment: The general solution is of the form $f(t+x)+g(t-x)$.  Unless I am missing something, the conditions $u(0,t)=0\implies f(t)+g(t)=e^t\sin t$ and $u(x,0)=0\implies f(x)+g(-x)=0$ are not compatible since they would together imply that $g(x)-g(-x)=e^x\sin x$.  The left-hand side is an odd function whereas the right-hand side is not.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, @Dr.MV. I'm feeling more sane now. Also, on the second line of your comment, I guess you meant to write $u(0,t)=e^t \sin{t} \Rightarrow (\ldots)$.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And you are correct; I did mean to write that.

Comment: Do you mean $u_{tt} - u_{xx} = 0$ on the first line?

Comment: @Siwel, yes. thanks for warning me.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that twice differentiable wave solutions defined for all $x$
are of the form $f(x+t)+g(x-t)$, but I think something else
applies here. The function $u(x,t) = e^{t-x}\sin(t-x)$ for $0\le x\le t$
and $u(x,t) = 0$ for $t\le x$, $\ t>0$ is probably what was intended. It is a weak solution not differentiable along the ray $x=t$.